# I cloned drools repo, tried to mvn install, but it give an error of unresolved parent POM

Tags: drools

I am using Ubuntu 18. I cloned drools repo to my computer, tried mvn clean install, but it gives me an error:

> [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   org.drools:drools:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact
>   org.kie:kie-parent:pom:7.21.0-SNAPSHOT in nexus
>   (http://nexus-cls.ptc.com/artifactory/public) and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11

When I import drools into eclipse, all poms give the same error

Comment: Have you solved it? Can you accept the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Try following this instructions to clone the repositories

https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap

Anyway a

```
git clone git@github.com:kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap.git
```

and

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

should suffice. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This time it proceed further, but still gives error:

Comment: This is the error I am getting:[WARNING] The POM for net.socialchange.doctype:doctype-changer:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-plugin:2.3.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find net.socialchange.doctype:doctype-changer:jar:1.1 in http://nexus-cls.ptc.com/artifactory/public was cached in the local repository,

Comment: This is unrelated to Drools as it doesn't depend on that jar. Try mvn -U or erasing the ~/.m2 folder